# kill subprocess.Popen().write after the process is finished

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to update the router with a python script with only one ssh call.
However, the kill() function is executed before the update starts.

```
process_1 = f' opkg update'
process_2 = f' echo process 2'

cmds = [
    f'{process_1}\n',
    f'{process_2}'
]

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "root@192.168.1.1"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

for cmd in cmds:
    proc.stdin.write(f'{cmd}'.encode())

proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.close()
proc.kill()
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `kill` on it?

Comment: Might you be looking for the method `wait` instead?

Comment: Without the kill() function i can not continue in the script

Comment: Why not, what exactly happened when you tried it?

Comment: @DanGetz it just gets stuck in the terminal
I will try with .run

Comment: Stuck after the commands are finished running?

Comment: exactly. if i want to execute without the kill() function for example print('str') it won't happen and the script stays (after executing the cmd) at the same place.
I have also tried with cmds = [' echo process 1 \n', ' echo process2'].

Comment: .wait() is the method I was looking for

Comment: Please post answer to your own question to close it

Comment: I rolled back your edit; your question should remain strictly a question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

.wait() is the method I was looking for

```
process_1 = f' opkg update'
process_2 = f' echo process 2'

cmds = [
    f'{process_1}\n',
    f'{process_2}'
]

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "root@192.168.1.1"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

for cmd in cmds:
    proc.stdin.write(f'{cmd}'.encode())

proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing commands to standard input of `ssh` is somewhat finicky. A much better solution is to switch to Paramiko, but if your needs are simple, just refactor to pass the commands as arguments to `ssh`.

```
result = subprocess.run(
    ["ssh", "root@192.168.1.1",
     "\n".join(cmds)],
    check=True)
```

Like the documentation already tells you, you should generally prefer `subprocess.run` (or its legacy siblings `check_call`, `check_output`, etc) over `Popen` whenever you can. The problems you were experiencing is one of the symptoms, and of course, the fixed code is also much shorter and easier to understand.

As a further aside, `f'{thing}'` is just a really clumsy way to write `thing` (or `str(thing)` if `thing` isn't already a string).

Comment: subprocess.run(["ssh", "root@192.168.1.1","\n".join(cmds)],check=True) is awesome, thanks!
Trying to figure out how to deal with non-zero exit status.

Comment: Just remove the `check=True` if you don't want failure to trigger a traceback. For further details, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538